# Rerun the lambda on timeout

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Working in a web scraping by python 3.I have a list of URLs, each URL have more than 100 article URLs(including pagination).

Added the script in lambda. First, it reads URLs from CSV file and sends each main URL to function where selects all href of each article.

all the above process works fine.

the issue is as we know lambda has a time out of 15 minutes, so we need to rerun the same with the final point where URL page number and the remaining URL.

CSV file is read by pandas and is converted as a directory.
select an object from the dictionary and pass to function with a regex of page, the number of pages to **scrape** (pagination).

can we store the current page and the remaining URLs in a local folder in lambda and renun the same, if so how can we do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Local storage in Lambda does not guarantee consistency. A new Lambda instance will be triggered and you will lose that data.

I would suggest having Cloudwatch cron event which will trigger a Lambda (let's call it DispatcherLambda). That lambda will look at the CSV file (maybe store that data better, like in DynamoDB?) and will decide how the work will be split. For example:

```
1-10 URLs: worker #1
11-20 URLs: worker #2
...
```

Once that is decided, that lambda will publish events to a SQS queue (the event input will contain that range). Subscribed to the queue, there will be another Lambda (WorkerLambda let's say) which will do the actual scraping. This way you will not have any issues with timeout, finish the work much sooner (invoking parallelism) and it is more fault tolerant (if a Lambda fails, SQS can fire it again).

Comment: thank you for immediate reply.
for Eg: http://www.lukoil.com/PressCenter/Pressreleases this web page has 200 pages each page has more than 10 articles.
for selecting all article per page it took more than 15 min.
we need to know till which page we collected the href of each article
then which all main URLs left.

I have a small idea at the start of each main url we start a schedule for 14 min.
at 14 th min store details + remaining the main URL in a file and upload it to S3.
on a rerun of lambda collect it from S3 do the process till the main URL finish.
please suggest

Comment: I would use the same principle as above then. A ScannerLambda which just checks number of pages, send each page to another SQS queue (should be no more than 30s), a DispatcherLambda will listen to it, get all links of that page (no more than 5-10s) and eventually send them to WorkerLambas. Just make sure to avoid duplicated articles considering new ones may be added during the scraping process.

Comment: The 14 minute timer has a more complex logic and it is more sensible for maintenance and issues.

Comment: if you want 100% accurate data, ScannerLambda also has to find absolute last article link (considering their order will stay the same and none is deleted). Last page DispatcherLambda should check if the received id matches the actual last one, if not, fire another DispatcherLambda with currentPage + 1 (do this recursively until the id is found or there are no more pages).

Comment: that already implemented. Lambda A reads csv file and has a for loop select 1 URL of 50 and pass to function which read all articles URL and send as SQS message to Lambda B.
go to the next page get all article href send the same to Lambda B, loops till the last page.
but time out occurs at the 150th page, there are 50 more pages and there are 49 more URLs.
we need to start from the 151st page and the next URL says 2nd one and do the above process again.

Comment: how can the same lambda be called parallelly? do you have any sample of the same

Comment: SQS being an event source for Lambda https://dzone.com/articles/amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source-to-aws-lambda-a-deep

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good case for [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) state machine. With a state machine, you can exit the Lambda when you are running low on time and return information about where you are in the process. That information can then be passed into the Lambda in its next execution, looping until you return something that indicates you are complete. With a standard workflow that looping can continue for up to a year (hopefully it wouldn't take that long).